# UIAttachmentBehavior in UITableViewCell just like Messages App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I want to replicate the attachment behavior of UITableViewCell, just like what Apple made in the Messages App.

I tried subclassing UITableViewCell and here is the code :

```
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];

self.attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.superview attachedToAnchor:self.superview.center];
[self.attachmentBehavior setFrequency:4.5];
[self.attachmentBehavior setDamping:0.3];

UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self]];

//gravity direction: right
[gravityBehavior setGravityDirection:CGVectorMake(0.0, -0.8)];

UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self]];
[collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"topBoundary" fromPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) toPoint:CGPointMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, 0.0f)];
[collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"bottomBoundary" fromPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, self.contentView.frame.size.height) toPoint:CGPointMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];

UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self]];
itemBehaviour.elasticity = 0.9;
[self.animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour];

[self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];
[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];
```

But, it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help me to reproduce the same functionality as the Messages app please ?

Edited :
I know that Apple uses UICollectionView instead tableview for the Messages App, but i hope there should be a way to do this kind of functionality through tableview also.

Comment: Any luck integrating it with UITableView?

Comment: Not yet.
Do you have any useful links to refer ?

Comment: Nothing yet. Still looking around. Do let me know if you come up with something.